# How to select a folder inside another without having to know the name

Tags: php, directory

How would I select the folder inside of another without having to know the name with PHP? Their is only one folder inside of the other. I know you can use `../../` to get folders above a directory and would assume that their is a method to do the same with folders down a directory.

Comment: does http://uk3.php.net/opendir help? you can use that to find the name of the folder if its the only one.

Comment: The issue here is that I won't know the folder name. It will be hidden to me and it will be relying on user files.

Comment: What command do you need the folder for, are you trying to open a file within a particular folder?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to list the contents of the folder.

Comment: In that case look at @Maarten's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is linux based, depending on your specific usecase the following might work:

```
/folderwithonedir/*/
```

Comment: My webserver is linux based but My computer is a windows machine. Is their anyway I could select a random folder inside? Their is only one in the folder.

Comment: It's dependent on your os, i would suggest to actually find out the name of the folder you are looking for

Comment: This would be the simplest solution, but it is an automated system that I am creating. I would just need to open the folder located a directory down such as `../` <<< Used to locate a directory up 1.

Comment: Yep i get what you're looking for but that doesn't exsist because a dir always has 1 parent but possibly multiple subdirs

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll have to find the folder name. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scandir()`](http://www.php.net/scandir) or [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) to get the contents of the directory and then your folder will probably the first or second item in the result, you can check that with [`is_dir()`](http://www.php.net/is_dir) in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (is_dir($file) === true)
    {
        $data[] = strval($file);
    }
}

$data has your directories
```